# Prolog: Size of list matches an integer

Tags: list, prolog

I'm very new to prolog. I have a size of list predicate. I'm trying to make another predicate that takes two arguments (an int, and a list) and it calls the size of list predicate on the passed in list and returns true if the list size matches the int passed in.

This is what I have so far.

```
size([],0).
size([H|T],N) :- size(T,N1), N is N1+1.

isEqual[X,Y] :- X/size[Y,N]. %X is an int representing expected length of list, Y is the list
```

Advice is welcomed.

Comment: What's wrong with just calling `size(L, X).` ? E.g, `size([a,b,c],3).` will give you true.

Comment: Ahhh this works! My beginner is showing. Thanks!

Comment: `size/2` is commonly called `length/2`.

Comment: What does the `isEqual[X,Y] :- X/size[Y,N]` notation mean? It's not valid Prolog syntax.